# shell script to transform a string to another form

Tags: shell

i want to transform a string from one form to another, for example if
input:

```
localhost -> ABC-NPCCache-Resource-Provisioning 2.3.1.1
```

output

```
ABC-NPCCache-Resource-Provisioning-2.3.1.1.tar.gz
```

i tried a lot but unable to find short way in shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this sed one-liner may give you a hand:

```
sed 's/.*-> //;s/ /-/;s/$/.tar.gz/'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  sed 's/.*-> //;s/ /-/;s/$/.tar.gz/'<<<'localhost -> ABC-NPCCache-Resource-Provisioning 2.3.1.1'    
ABC-NPCCache-Resource-Provisioning-2.3.1.1.tar.gz
```

or with awk:

```
awk -F' -> ' '{gsub(/ /,"-",$2);$0=$2".tar.gz"}7'
```

Comment: echo $(sed 's/.*-> //;s/ /-/;s/$/.tar.gz/'<<<$backup)  i tried this command but output m getting JDV-NPCCache-Resource-Provisioning-2.3.1.1   .tar.gz is  one extra space after 2.3.1.1

Comment: my input is: localhost -> ABC-NPCCache-Resource-Provisioning 2.3.1.1

Comment: @anup your input has trailing spaces then, try change `s/$/.tar.gz/;` into `s/ *$/.tar.gz/`

Answer (score 0):

`sed` kan remember a matching string (a number of characters different from a space) and show it like this:

```
mystring='localhost -> ABC-NPCCache-Resource-Provisioning 2.3.1.1 '
echo "${mystring}" | sed -r 's/.*-> ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*).*/\1.\2.tar.gz/'
# result:
ABC-NPCCache-Resource-Provisioning.2.3.1.1.gz
```